# Load css image from a host where the image folder host name path is generated dynamically

Tags: html, css

How should i refernce the image in the image folder to the style.css in remote host. where the folder will have a dynamic URL.

Folder Structure:

Gillete_Ad [Folder]

- index.html
- images
- Style.css from www.xyz.com/style.css

I am working on creating a ad. where the style.css is used from a different host.I have a ad unit folder which contains index.html and image folder which will be zipped and uploaded to our ad server to create a ad tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.thesite.com/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: I think you didn't get my question.